# How to read this formula for win chance probability?

Tags: probability

[image]

```
Explanation:
Prob = Win prediction
e = 2.71828 (Euler)
q = 2.012 (based on historical data; constant)
R1 = Rating player 1
R2 = Rating player 2
```

From the formula comes a number between 0 and 1. This is the win predication for the
player.

```
Let's take:
R1 = 5.5000
R2 = 5.3000
```

This should result in a win chance of player 1: **40%** vs player 2: **60%**.

```
My guess was:
prob = 1 / 1 + 2.71828 ^ -2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)

The result is 1,0267442292 which is not a number between 0 and 1, I would expect 0.4.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing two parentheses

I get $\frac{1}{1+2.71828^{-2.012(5.5-5.3)}}=0.599\,26$ while
you calculated $\frac{1}{1}+2.71828^{-2.012}\ast (5.5-5.3)=
1.\, 026\,7$.

Comment: Jessica thank you so much that was it... 1 / (1 + 2,71828 ^ (-2,012 * (5,5 - 5,3)) that gave 0.599 the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Since $e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)} > 0$, you should have that $1+e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)} > 1$, and hence $\frac{1}{1+e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)}}<1$ .. so something is indeed off.

Now, you write that you calculated

$1 / 1 + e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)}$

I wonder if you forgot some parentheses there, i.e. maybe you ended up calculating

$(1/1) + e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)}$

rather than:

$1 /( 1 + e^{-2.012 * (5.5 - 5.3)})$

or something like that?

Anyway, the formula clearly should get you a value between $0$ and $1$, so nothing's wrong with the formula. It's something with how you calculated it.

Comment: I upvoted because you helped me out with at least establishing that the formula was correct. Thanks for thinking with me.